# Making a calculation based on the time module with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to output an altered time based on the "time" module in Py. For instance. I gather raw_input for the script from a user and based on that input I want to get system time and subtract a number of days from it and use that time for another step.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are examples of all these steps [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#module-datetime).

Answer (score 0):

The [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) is likely what you want.

Here is an example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> s = raw_input('Input year month day hour minute second: ')
Input year month day hour minute second: 2011 10 31 14 30 00
'2011 10 31 14 30 00'
>>> fields = map(int, s.split())
>>> fields
[2011, 10, 31, 14, 30, 0]
>>> userdate = datetime(*[2011, 10, 31, 14, 30, 0])
>>> userdate
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 31, 14, 30)
>>> userdate - timedelta(days=20)
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 11, 14, 30)

>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 31, 11, 38, 34, 856511)
>>> now + timedelta(hours=2)
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 31, 13, 38, 34, 856511)
```